# Why won't my button work in this other program with multiple java classes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following java classes:

AddItem.java

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    EditText editTextItemName,editTextBrand;
    Button buttonAddItem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        editTextItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_item_name);
        editTextBrand = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_brand);

        buttonAddItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    
    private void   addItemToSheet() {

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
        final String name = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String brand = editTextBrand.getText().toString().trim();
        
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
                parmas.put("action","addItem");
                parmas.put("itemName",name);
                parmas.put("brand",brand);

                return parmas;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeOut = 50000;
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==buttonAddItem){
            addItemToSheet();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
```

etc... I'll leave this one out because it's long. It obtains location information and it's working properly along with all of its buttons.

MainActivity2.Java:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonAddItem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        buttonAddItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==buttonAddItem){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

This is how I call everything in my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"/>
    <activity android:name=".AddItem"/>
</application>
```

Any ideas why btn_add_item from main_activity.xml isn't doing anything here? :/ It should be sending text from et_brand and et_item_name to my Google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason why you are getting an error might be because you are checking

```
v==buttonAddItem
```

Instead of checking if the ids are the same.

```
v.getId()==R.id.btn_add_item
```

Is what you need to do.

Comment: Just for ss and gs, are you positive that its being called? Like, if you put a log statement in, does it show up?

Comment: Not sure if it's being called. I'm new to Java. I'll research how to put in a log statement and get back to you.

Comment: It should just be `Log.d("TAG HERE", "MESSAGE HERE");`

Comment: You're 100% right. I wasn't calling it. Although now I have a weird error where if I call it my entire gui resets and I have to press the button twice for it to work. but I should be able to troubleshoot that. Thank you for your help!